# The elements on my page keep moving when the page is resized

Tags: positioning, element

I did check the other questions, but none of them fixed my problem. When I resize the page, my elements are moving everywhere, all squashed up. I even tried doing a wrapper div, and that didn't help. Are we allowed to post web sites? Because I have the site live.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Promises!-Contact</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<style>
#body  {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 370px;
  height: 1%;
  margin-top: 100px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px dotted #00A396;
  background-clip: content-box;
  background-color: #F8B72E;
  text-align: justify;
  font-family: Kirvy;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0%;
  padding: 0%;
}

p { padding: 10px;}

#title {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 24px;
  top-margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

nav {
  font-family: KBAStitchInTime;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #EC225F;
  right: 220px;
  top: 140px;
  position: relative;}

#dot1  {
  font-size: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;}

#dot2 {
  font-size: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;}

#dot3 {
  font-size: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;}

#dot4 {
  font-size: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 20px;}

 a:link { color:#EC225F; text-decoration:none; }
 a:visited{ color: purple; }
 a:hover{ color: ;}
 a:active {}   
body {background-color: #262626;
  text-align: left;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<nav>
  <span id="dot1">.</span><a href="about.html">About</a><br>
  <span id="dot2">.</span><a href="pages.html">Pages</a><br>
  <span id="dot3">.</span><a href="poems.html">Poems</a><br>
  <span id="dot4">.</span><a href="index.html">Home</a><br> 
</nav>
<div id="body">
  <p id="title">Contact!</p>
  <p> I love getting mail! Find me at:</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Instead of posting you whole site, you can jsfiddle for example.

Comment: Ultimately, I want to find out why the elements keep moving. The nav keeps going over the main body. I posted the site thought because I thought it was ready to go live, but someone pointed out these errors to me.

Comment: Is there anyone who can suggest some solutions?